# Struggling with compare last 2/3/4 characters Java (repl.it 018 - Conditional Statement Practice 4)

Tags: java, if-statement, compare, conditional-statements, equals

Dear Stackoverflow community I am Struggling with one task on repl.it (018) Conditional Statements 4

So they want me to do that :

Instructions from your teacher:
 For you to do:

Given a string variable "word", do the following tests

If the word ends in "y", print "-ies"
If the word ends in "ey", print "-eys"
If the word ends in "ife", print "-ives"
If none of the above is true, print "-s"
No more than one should be printed.

and my code looks like this :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("In:");
    String word = inp.nextLine();
    //DO NOT CHANGE ABOVE CODE!  Write your code below

    if(word.endsWith("y"){
      System.out.println("-ies");
    }
    else if(word.endsWith("ey")){
      System.out.println("-eys");
    }
    else if(word.endsWith("ife")){
      System.out.println("-ives");
    }
    else{

      System.out.println("-s");
    }
  }
}
```

When I run it for example my input is :Hey

and of course my code will go through the code and see if the first statement is correct and yes it is equal because y = y at the end and that is WRONG!

My question is how can i let my code compare the last 2 or 3 characters so it will print out the right value when I input Hey.

If I input Hey it should print out :

-eys and not -ies

Ty

Comment: The specifications for your assignment leaves some room for interpretation, but basically you just need to re-arrange the `if` clauses to get the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ending with "ey" is a subset of ending with "y", your 2nd `if` will never be true.

Change the order of your tests to the most specific first:

```
if(word.endsWith("ey"){
  System.out.println("-eys");
}
else if(word.endsWith("y")){
  System.out.println("-ies");
}
else if(word.endsWith("ife")){
  System.out.println("-ives");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

reorder the conditions as such:

```
if(word.endsWith("ey")){
   System.out.println("-eys");
}
else if(word.endsWith("ife")){
   System.out.println("-ives");
}
else if(word.endsWith("y")){
   System.out.println("-ies");
}
else{    
   System.out.println("-s");
}
```

This means we hoist the condition that is most specific and put the less specific ones below.

I've put the `else if(word.endsWith("y"))` as the last of the `else if`s but it really doesn't matter where within the `else if` chaining you put it as long as it's before the condition `if(word.endsWith("ey"))` things should be fine.